# Pyserial RFID Reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to write a python script to capture the output of a RFID reader. The RFID reader is connecting to a computer using a usb to serial connector. The RFID reader is sending hex data. The test RFID tag is "CC FF FF 11 32 01 0E 01 30 08 33 B2 DD D9 01 40 00 00 00 00 EB"

The issue im running into is that the script is recording the following information when the tag is read "b'\xcc\xff\xff\x112\x01\x0e\x010\x083\xb2\xdd\xd9\x01@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xeb'"

Where im getting stuck is that some of the recorded bytes are displaying the incorrect hex characters. I have tried to decode the bytes using .decode("utf-8") and .decode("ascii") thinking pyserial was encoding the bytes but the data was still incorrect.

Here is the script:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

while(ser.is_open == True):
    incomingByte = ser.read(21)
    print(incomingByte)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using the following code.

```
while(ser.is_open == True):
    rfidtag = ''
    incomingByte = ser.read(21)
    print(incomingByte)
    for i in incomingByte:
        rfidtag = rfidtag + hex(i)
```